# Clustered index on integer column surprisingly slow

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have an `InnoDB` table with 750,000 records. Its primary key is a `BIGINT`.

When I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

it takes 900ms. `explain` shows that the index is not used.

When I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE pk >= 3000000;
```

it takes 400ms. `explain` shows that the index, in this case, is used.

I am looking to do fast counts where `x >= pk >= y`.

It is my understanding that since I use the primary key of the table, I am using a clustered index, and that therefore the rows are (physically?) ordered by this index. Should it then not be very, very fast to do this count? I was expecting the result to be available in a dozen milliseconds or so.

I have read that faster results can be expected if I select only a small part of the table. I am however interested in doing these counts of ranges. Perhaps I should organize my data in a different way?

In a different case, I have a table with spatial data and use an RTREE index, and then I use `MBRContains` to count matching rows (and on a secondary index). Surprisingly, this is faster than the simple case above.

Comment: Hi use COUNT(1) instead of COUNT(*) and use clustered index at pk field

Comment: Elapsed time can be highly dependent from the fact if tha table or index is cached or not. You should always repeat the measurement. Additionaly the count can profit from index access for a large ranges only if the index fast full scan acces method is implemented, which I'm not sure is the case for  InoDB

Comment: @RahulBiswas That is a very good idea. The MySQL developers had the same idea, though, so (for InnoDB), count(1) and count(*) are completely identical.

Comment: For InnoDB, the data is stored "in the primary key". Reading the whole table and using the primary key to read the whole table are the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.  This means that the data is sorted by the PK and `where pk BETWEEN x AND y` must read all the rows from `x` through `y`.

So, how does it do a scan by PK?  It must read the data blocks.  They are bulky in that they have other columns.

But what about `COUNT(*)` without a `WHERE`?  In this case, the Optimizer looks for the least-bulky index and counts the rows in it.  So...

If you have a secondary index, it will use that.

If you only have the PK, then it will read the entire table to do the count.

That is, the artificial addition of a secondary index on the narrowest column is likely to speedup `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl`.

But wait...  Be sure to run each timing test twice.  The first time (after a restart) must read the needed blocks from disk.  Slow.

The second time all the blocks are likely to be sitting in RAM.  Much faster.

`SPATIAL` and `FULLTEXT` indexing complicated this discussion.  Especially if you have 2 parts to the `WHERE`, one with Spatial or Fulltext, one with a regular test.

`COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` are identical.  `COUNT(x)` checks x for being `NOT NULL` before including the row in the tally.

Comment: All true, but `where x >= pk => y` wouldn't work as intended at all. It evaluates the first comparison to a boolean (0 or 1) then that value is compared to `y`. It would be better to use `where pk between y and x`.

Comment: @BillKarwin - OK, it is not bad syntax, but rather "it does not do what you think it should".  I reworded my Answer to make my point without using that expression.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for this good explanation. Your answer led me to other answers by yourself to similar questions, and I have a better understanding of how `count` works as a result.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I sound like a 'broken record'.